# How to address pre-image of boundary points when the function only maps to the interior?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose a function $f$ maps from all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ on to the interior of a closed set $C$.

Then what can we say about $f^{-1}(C)$?

That is, how do we deal with the boundary points?

Does this set equal to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Or is it a "piecewise function", equal to $\mathbb{R}^n$ on the interior and the empty set for boundary.

I think the latter is right but I am not sure about the convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f^{-1}(C)$ by definition is the set of all pre-images of things in $C$.  By your definition,  the range of $f$ is the interior of $C$,  so every point of $\mathbb{R}^n$ will be in the pre-image.  The boundary points don't have any pre-images, but that doesn't matter.  You may be being confused, remember $f^{-1}$ is a set valued function,  taking sets to sets.   Now,  $f^{-1}(\partial C)=\emptyset$,  but that doesn't change the overall answer.

Comment: So is it correct to say then $f^{-1}(C) = \mathbb{R}^n$? I see since $\emptyset \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Yes,  since $f^{-1}(C)=f^{-1}\text{ (interior of C)}\cup f^{-1}(\partial C)$